# struts2 form validation not working with jsp and action class

Tags: jsp, struts2

'No result defined for action and result input' message is displayed when applying validation using validate() method .How to overcome it?

Comment: Do you want to overcome a validation?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is a `result` for "`input`" written in the `struts.xml` for when the validation fails:

```
 <result name="input">/YourPage.jsp</result>
```

If you don't have this, you'll get a: `"No result defined for action xxx.xxx.YourAction and result input"` error.

Also check mapping of HTML field elements with Action class fields.